# How to loop over c++ vectors of vectors with unknown depth?

Tags: c++, loops, object, recursion, data-structures

I have a rendering architecture utilizing the following structure:

- `Model`: base level object
- `Assembly:` contains `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Model>>` as well as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Assembly>>` (that is, it can contain models or subassemblies, which intern can contain subassemblies, etc.)
- `Universe`: Top level; contains `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Model>>` as well as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Assembly>>`.  (`Universe` is treated as separate from an `Assembly` because it manages many other things as well)

I need to be able to loop over every model, which can be contained either in the `Universe` directly, or in an `Assembly` (possibly nested in several "sub" assemblies).  What would be a convenient way of doing this?  Inside of the Universe I need something like this:

```
for (auto& model : models) {
    ...
}

for (auto& assembly : assemblies) {
    for (auto& model : assembly->models) {
        ...
    }

    // Recurse into potentially nested assemblies?
    ...
}
```

I need the Universe to be able to access the data in each model, preferably without copying it.  I was thinking of implementing some method within the `Assembly` class that can be called recursively, but I'm not sure how to then propagate that up to the `Universe` such that it can do what is required (which is things like obtaining the geometry data stored in the Model to build ray tracing acceleration structure, to rasterize, etc.)

How might I do this?  Or how could I restructure things to get the behavior that is desired?

Comment: A recursive function perhaps?

Comment: The old-fashioned method of using a nested `for` loop, where the sizes of the nested vectors is obtained before the `for` statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews but its not necessarily just the size of the nested vectors but how nested they are.  Effectively, I'd need to set how many nested `for` loops, no?  How would you be able to change that at runtime?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat so along the lines of an `Assembly::getNext()` function that recursively calls each assembly's sub assemblies to return the "next" model?  It would need a way for the current most nested assembly to signal that its completed, and the next highest assembly should iterate to its next sub assembly.  How would you be able to signal that though?

Comment: Your function should accept another function as a parameter (use `std::function`), and call it for every model in this assembly, then call itself on every assembly in this assembly. Is this clear, or should I post a code sample?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not sure I completely follow so a code sample may be helpful if you get a chance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive function. Take another function as a parameter, and call it for every model.

I've simplified your class structure for the demo a bit, but the idea should be the same.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Model
{
    std::string model_name;
};

struct Assembly
{
    std::vector<Model> models;
    std::vector<Assembly> assemblies;

    void ForEachModel(const std::function<void(Model &model)> &func)
    {
        for (Model &model : models)
            func(model);
        for (Assembly &assembly : assemblies)
            assembly.ForEachModel(func);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Assembly a{
        .models = {{"a"}, {"b"}},
        .assemblies = {
            {.models = {{"c"}, {"d"}}},
            {
                .models = {{"e"}, {"f"}},
                .assemblies = {
                    {.models = {{"g"}, {"h"}}},
                    {.models = {{"i"}, {"j"}}},
                },
            },
        },
    };

    a.ForEachModel([](Model &m){std::cout << m.model_name << '\n';});
}
```

Comment: Great example, thanks for writing this out!